# Jaxb with baseclass doesn't serialize derived elements

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb

I have a list of modules in a tree like structure. The baseclass contains the childs and some generic property, while the derived class should provide it's individual fields. Now when I try to serialize this with JAXB I get only the members of the baseclass but not the ones from the derived classes.

## Application.java

```
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Emulators emulators = new Emulators();
            emulators.addChild(new VICEModule());
            emulators.addChild(new VICEModule());

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(emulators.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); // Pretty print
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(emulators, sw);
            String s = sw.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception:"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

## ModuleBase.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class ModuleBase
{
    private List<ModuleBase> mChilds = new ArrayList<>();
    private String mModuleId;
    private String mModuleName;

    public ModuleBase(String oModuleId, String oModuleName)
    {
        setModuleId(oModuleId);
        setModuleName(oModuleName);
    }

    public void addChild(ModuleBase oModuleNode)
    {
        mChilds.add(oModuleNode);
    }

    @XmlElement(name="ModuleList")
    public List<ModuleBase> getChildModules()
    {
        return mChilds;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getModuleId()
    {
        return mModuleId;
    }

    public void setModuleId(String oModuleId)
    {
        mModuleId = oModuleId;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getModuleName()
    {
        return mModuleName;
    }

    public void setModuleName(String oModuleName)
    {
        mModuleName = oModuleName;
    }
}
```

## Emulators.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Emulators")
public class Emulators
    extends ModuleBase 
{
    public Emulators()
    {
        super("IdEmu129872q53", "Emulators");
    }
}
```

## VICEModule.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlRootElement(name = "VICEModule")
public class VICEModule
    extends ModuleBase
{
    private String mInstallationPath;
    private int mPort;

    public VICEModule()
    {
        super("Id123456", "Vice");

        mPort = 6510;
    }

    //@XmlElement(name="InstallationPath")
    @XmlValue
    public String getInstallationPath()
    {
        return mInstallationPath;
    }

    public void setInstallationPath(String oPath)
    {
        mInstallationPath = oPath;
    }

    //@XmlElement(name="Port")
    @XmlValue
    public int getPort()
    {
        return mPort;
    }

    public void setPort(int nPort)
    {
        mPort = nPort;
    }
}
```

Now when I serialize it, I get the following XML where the VICEModule values are missing and also the module is listed as `ModuleList` instead of `VICEModule` and the base fields are put as tags instead of attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Emulators>
    <ModuleList>
        <moduleId>Id123456</moduleId>
        <moduleName>Vice</moduleName>
    </ModuleList>
    <ModuleList>
        <moduleId>Id123456</moduleId>
        <moduleName>Vice</moduleName>
    </ModuleList>
    <moduleId>IdEmu129872q53</moduleId>
    <moduleName>Emulators</moduleName>
</Emulators>
```

So what this should look like is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Emulators ModuleId="IdEmu129872q53" ModuleName="Emulators">
    <VICEModule ModuleId="Id1" ModuleName="Name">
        <InstallationPath>Path1</InstallationPath>
        <Port>6510</Port>
    </VICEModule>
    <VICEModule ModuleId="Id2" ModuleName="Name">
        <InstallationPath>Path2</InstallationPath>
        <Port>6511</Port>
    </VICEModule>
</Emulators>
```

When I use the `VICEModule` as the baseclass, then the XML looks more like it (still without the attributes though).

Answer (score 0):

Writing this small demo app helped, because now I could more easily play around with the marshalling and finally got it working. I'm posting the changes here, to make this sample complete in case somebody needs it as a reference. `Emulators.java` was not changed, so it's not listed in the answer.

Short answer:

I had to add `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` to my getter for the child modules in order to convert the resulting XML node into a named node as I want it to. Additionally in the main application I had to traverse the tree and collect all classes that are used, so that I can pass it to the `JAXBContext`.

## Application.java

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Application
{
    public static List<Class<?>> createClasses(ModuleBase oModule)
    {
        List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.add(oModule.getClass());

        for(ModuleBase module : oModule.getChildModules())
        {
            List<Class<?>> cls = createClasses(module);
            classes.addAll(cls);
        }

        return classes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Emulators emulators = new Emulators();
            emulators.addChild(new VICEModule("Id1", "VICE V1", "V1 Path", 6510));
            emulators.addChild(new VICEModule("Id2", "VICE V2", "V2 Path", 6511));

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            List<Class<?>> classes = createClasses(emulators);
            Class<?>[] cls = new Class<?>[classes.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++)
                cls[i] = classes.get(i);

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(cls);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); // Pretty print
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(emulators, sw);
            String s = sw.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception:"+e);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

## ModuleBase.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class ModuleBase
{
    private List<ModuleBase> mChilds = new ArrayList<>();

    private String mModuleId;
    private String mModuleName;

    public ModuleBase(String oModuleId, String oModuleName)
    {
        setModuleId(oModuleId);
        setModuleName(oModuleName);
    }

    public void addChild(ModuleBase oModuleNode)
    {
        mChilds.add(oModuleNode);
    }

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    public List<ModuleBase> getChildModules()
    {
        return mChilds;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getModuleId()
    {
        return mModuleId;
    }

    public void setModuleId(String oModuleId)
    {
        mModuleId = oModuleId;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getModuleName()
    {
        return mModuleName;
    }

    public void setModuleName(String oModuleName)
    {
        mModuleName = oModuleName;
    }
}
```

## VICEModule.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "VICEModule")
public class VICEModule
    extends ModuleBase
{
    private String mInstallationPath;
    private int mPort;

    public VICEModule()
    {
        super("Id123456", "Vice");

        mPort = 6510;
    }

    public VICEModule(String oId, String oName, String oPath, int nPort)
    {
        super(oId, oName);

        setInstallationPath(oPath);
        setPort(nPort);
    }

    @XmlElement(name="InstallationPath")
    public String getInstallationPath()
    {
        return mInstallationPath;
    }

    public void setInstallationPath(String oPath)
    {
        mInstallationPath = oPath;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Port")
    public int getPort()
    {
        return mPort;
    }

    public void setPort(int nPort)
    {
        mPort = nPort;
    }
}
```

Now the XML renders exactly as intended with storing all the objects from derived classes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Emulators moduleId="IdEmu129872q53" moduleName="Emulators">
    <VICEModule moduleId="Id1" moduleName="VICE V1">
        <InstallationPath>V1 Path</InstallationPath>
        <Port>6510</Port>
    </VICEModule>
    <VICEModule moduleId="Id2" moduleName="VICE V2">
        <InstallationPath>V2 Path</InstallationPath>
        <Port>6511</Port>
    </VICEModule>
</Emulators>
```